# Why "go test -v" doesn't see the GOPATH or GOPATH but "go env" does?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

The application works fine when I run it locally with:
$ dev_appserver.py app.yaml

However, when I attempt to run tests, the ENV doesn't seem to be set.

$ go test -v

```
skincare.go:6:5: cannot find package "appengine" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/appengine (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/bryan/go/src/appengine (from $GOPATH)
skincare.go:7:5: cannot find package "appengine/datastore" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/appengine/datastore (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/bryan/go/src/appengine/datastore (from $GOPATH)
skincare.go:8:5: cannot find package "appengine/user" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/appengine/user (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/bryan/go/src/appengine/user (from $GOPATH)
```

$ go env

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/bryan/go/"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Answer (score 3):

`$GOPATH` should not not contain the `src` part of the path. So instead of pointing to `/Users/bryan/go/src/` it should point to **`/Users/bryan/go`**.

Comment: Are you sure they're exactly the same errors. Please post if different.

Comment: The path on the errors did change and I updated them on OP.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your tests are failing because you're invoking them directly with `go test` rather than using the App Engine SDK's test runner, `goapp test`, which will link you to the appengine package when it runs.